# Optical Flow Estimation

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, opticalflow

[image]How might you calculate the velocity/speed of an object from a ".flo" output (I used deep learning approach to generate optical flow. Output is a ****.flo file which in turn is converted to a color image for visualization)? Image attached!

Comment: This is pretty broad for SO. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to make a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Give some things a try and see if you can pare it down to specific problems you are running into.

Comment: Thanks! I figure my way out.